# Restaurar DataBase, SQL server 2008 R2 desde Consulta

Tags: sql-server

Quiero hacer esto mediante consulta segun los pasos me preguntaba ¿cual seria el Scrip consulta para este SQL server 2008 R2? ojo sin tener previo el Mdf ni el ldf en el disco duro antes de la restauracion osea quiero que el .bak me los cree la consulta.

[image: Quiero hacer esto mediante consulta segun los pasos me preguntaba ¿cual seria el Scrip consulta para este SQL server 2008 R2?]

Comment: Las preguntas siempre deben ir acompañadas de lo que haz tratado hasta el momento y los fallos que haz tenido, lee por favor [ask]

Comment: Amigo si usted lee se dara cuenta que no es de Fallos se trata de una consulta a partir de la creacion de un bak para crear uno desde sql Obviamente si no he creado la consulta para crear restauracion NO TENDRE ERRORES. sin embargo estan saliendo solitos por que en la imagen lo explico bien.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que necesitas algo como esto:

```
RESTORE DATABASE DB_Clients
FROM DISK = 'C:\DB_Clients.bak'
WITH REPLACE
WITH MOVE 'YourMDFLogicalName' TO '<MDF file path>',
MOVE 'YourLDFLogicalName' TO '<LDF file path>'
```

Comment: casi amigo pero este me pide que tengo que tener los mdf y ldf ya en el disco duro pre-instalado o ya dentro de el sql server. pero en un supuesto robo solo tendria el .bak y quiero que este me haga la funcion del asistente. Gracias.

Comment: para eso necesitas WITH MOVE, editaré mi respuesta para ver si te funciona.

Comment: me salio este error: Msg 155, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
'MOVE' is not a recognized RESTORE option.

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta, intenta colocando los respectivos paths.

Comment: quedaria asi?RESTORE DATABASE GM_Stuff
FROM DISK = 'C:\ShaiyaServer\BackUp\GM_Stuff.bak'
WITH MOVE 'GM_Stuff.mdf' TO 'GM_Stuff.mdf',
MOVE 'GM_Stuff.ldf' TO 'GM_Stuff.ldf'

Comment: En el WITH MOVE después de TO debes especificar la ruta de ubicación, ejemplo:
WITH 
MOVE 'DB_Clients' TO 'D:\SQLServer\Data\DB_Clients.mdf',
MOVE 'DB_Clients_Other' TO 'D:\SQLServer\Log\DB_Clients.ldf'